# Binding Source changes current item when datagrid looses focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, observablecollection

I have a WinForm with 6 DataGridViews in VB.Net 2010, each with their own binding source. I have one additional main DataGridView that controls what is in the other grids. This is the only grid that allows a new record to be added. All others are controlled programmatically. The main grid binding source is bound to an observable collection of objects, with an additional binding source for one of the class objects from the collection.

My issue is that when I click on the new row in the main grid, everything clears as it is suppose to by instantiating a new single class object, but when I tab off of the grid or click or anything else, the binding source for the grid resets its current item to the first item in the grid. If I set the single object binding source to the new instantiated object, it clears the first item in the collection as well. This does not happen on any other screens where we use DataGridViews bound to observable collections. What am I missing?

Sample code of grid click implementation

```
Private Sub dgvReports_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvReports.CellClick
If e.RowIndex < 0 Or dgvReports.SelectedRows.Count < 0 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not dgvReports.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
    objReport = dgvReports.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem
    objReport.SerializeToDB()
    intSelIndex = e.RowIndex
    objReport = objReport.Deserialize()
    If objReport.MsgObject.ErrMsg > "" Then
        objReport.MsgObject.DisplayErrMsg()
    End If
    btnDelete.Enabled = True And Not blnReadOnly
Else
    objReport = New RBL.Report
    objReport.GlobalID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    intSelIndex = e.RowIndex
    btnDelete.Enabled = False
End If
' The following 3 lines of code causes the first record in grid to be reset
' but works in other implementations    
'If objReport IsNot Nothing Then
    'bsReport.DataSource = objReport
'End If

btnApply.Enabled = False
UpdateReportObjects()
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateReportObjects()
Dim objRprt As RBL.Report = Nothing

If dgvReports.SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then
    objRprt = dgvReports.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem
End If

' Set all local observable collections to Report properties
If objReport.GlobalID = objRprt.GlobalID Then
    RptFieldLst = objReport.ReportFields
    RptTableLst = objReport.TableList
    DisplayFieldLst = objReport.DisplayFields
    SortFldLst = objReport.SortList
Else
' Instantiate new collections and set to new Report object properties
    RptTableLst = New RBL.ReportTables()
    RptFieldLst = New RBL.ReportFields()
    DisplayFieldLst = New RBL.ReportFields()
    NonDisplayFieldLst = New RBL.ReportFields()
    SortFldLst = New RBL.ReportSortOrders()
    objReport.TableList = RptTableLst
    objReport.ReportFields = RptFieldLst
    objReport.DisplayFields = DisplayFieldLst
    objReport.SortList = SortFldLst
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any code to display? It seems like you have some kind of custom functionality in some an "on leave event".

Comment: There is no lost focus or leave event in the code. I really can't post actual code as it is prorietary. I may be able to dummy up some.

Comment: Do you have any "on selection changed event"? If I'm not mistaken I believe that when a dgv is repainted it selects the first object until if finds a row that was selected before the repaint.

Comment: I am not currently using the selection changed event, although our team has been discussing moving all of our cellclick events into the selection changed event so that we handle row changes from arrow keys as well as mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been discovered, and as usual, the finger points back at myself. DataSource for the observable collection's binding source and the single item's binding source where being set to the same variable object, the single class object. 
Problem solved.